# How to implement a method which accepts a string parameter and returns a JSON format in PHP

Tags: php, html

Below is an example of a data structure that defines a fruit’s color:

```
array(
  "red" => array("apple, strawberry"),
  "yellow" => array("lemon", "ripe mango")
)
```

> Implement the function getFruits method, which accepts color as a
>   string parameter and returns all fruits for that color in JSON format
>   (see example below).
>
> For example, the call $fruitcolors->getFruits("red"); should return:
>
> { "color":"red", "fruits": ["apple", "strawberry"]}
>
> If a call doesn’t have fruits for that $fruitcolors-
>   getFruits("violet"); color, it should return:
>
> { "color":"violet", "fruits":[] }

```
<?php
class FruitColor
{
  private $fruitcolor;

  function FruitColor($fruitcolor)
  {
    $this->fruitcolor = $fruitcolor;
  }

  public function getFruits($color)
  {
    // @todo: implement here
    return NULL;
  }
}

$fruitcolor = new FruitColor(array(
    "red" => array("apple", "strawberry"),
    "yellow" => array("lemon", "ripe mango")
));

echo $fruitcolor->getFruits("red");
echo "\n";
echo $fruitcolor->getFruits("violet");
```

Comment: That input data does not make any sense. Either it should be an array holding separate elements, or a string holding comma separated values. But not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class FruitColor {

    private $fruitcolor;

    function __construct($fruitcolor)
    {
        $this->fruitcolor = $fruitcolor;
    }
    public function getFruits($color)
    {
        $fruits = array();
        if (isset($this->fruitcolor[$color])) {
            $fruits = $this->fruitcolor[$color];
        }
        return json_encode(array("color" => $color, "fruits" => $fruits));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

class FruitColor {
    private $data;

    function FruitColor($fruitcolors) {
        $this->data = $fruitcolors;
    }

    public function getFruits($color) {
        $fruits = [];
        if (isset($this->data[$color]) && is_array($this->data[$color])) {
            $fruits = $this->data[$color];
        }
        return json_encode(array("color" => $color, "fruits" => $fruits));
    }
}

$fruitcolor = new FruitColor([
    "red" => ["apple", "strawberry"],
    "yellow" => ["lemon", "ripe mango"]
]);

var_dump($fruitcolor->getFruits("red"));
var_dump($fruitcolor->getFruits("yellow"));
var_dump($fruitcolor->getFruits("violet"));
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(47) "{"color":"red","fruits":["apple","strawberry"]}"
string(50) "{"color":"yellow","fruits":["lemon","ripe mango"]}"
string(30) "{"color":"violet","fruits":[]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class FruitColor{

    private $fruitcolor;

    public function __construct( $fruitcolor ){
        $this->fruitcolor = $fruitcolor;
    }

    public function getFruits( $color ){
        if( array_key_exists( $color, $this->fruitcolor ) ){
            return json_encode( (object)array('color'=>$color, 'fruits' => $this->fruitcolor[ $color ]) );
        }
        return json_encode( (object)array('color'=>$color, 'fruits' => array() ) );
    }
}




$arr=array(
    "red"       => array("apple", "strawberry"),
    "yellow"    => array("lemon", "ripe mango")
);


$obj=new FruitColor( $arr );


$red=$obj->getFruits( 'red' );
$yellow=$obj->getFruits( 'yellow' );
$violet=$obj->getFruits( 'violet' );


printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $red,1));
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $yellow,1));
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $violet,1));
```

Will output:

```
{"color":"red","fruits":["apple","strawberry"]}
{"color":"yellow","fruits":["lemon","ripe mango"]}
{"color":"violet","fruits":[]}
```